# Selecting XML Data from SQL query - No values returned

Tags: sql, sql-server

Xml Column returns no rows.
Below created a table type and xml value inserted into that table. After             executing the below mentioned two queries no value is returned.
Xml data is a valid data.

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE (Id INT IDENTITY (1,1), XMLDATA XML)

INSERT INTO @test
SELECT '
<TXLife xmlns="http://ACORD.org/Standards/Life/2" xmlns:tx="http://ACORD.org/Standards/Life/2" Version="2.20.00">
    <TXLifeRequest PrimaryObjectID="Holding_1">
        <CorrelationGUID>4b30545a-158b-441a-a37a-0b259f757059</CorrelationGUID>
    </TXLifeRequest>
</TXLife>'

SELECT 
      Id
    , XMLDATA.query('//CorrelationGUID') AS 'TransType'
    , XMLDATA
FROM @test

SELECT C.value('./CorrelationGUID[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS 'TransType'
FROM @test
CROSS APPLY XMLDATA.nodes('/TXLife/TXLifeRequest') n (C)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if I test your code with `CREATE TABLE`, [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4d160/1) and [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4d160/3), the unfiltered select works just fine. However, the second filtered select returns no results.

If I alter the query to to specify the right namespace, like in [@Devart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18461103/659190)'s answer,

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://ACORD.org/Standards/Life/2')
SELECT
        C.value('./CorrelationGUID[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS 'TransType'
    FROM
        Test
    CROSS APPLY
        XMLDATA.nodes('/TXLife/TXLifeRequest') n (C)
```

You can see, [it works as expected](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4d160/9).

Comment: `TransType` is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @XML XML
SELECT  @XML = '
<TXLife xmlns="http://ACORD.org/Standards/Life/2" xmlns:tx="http://ACORD.org/Standards/Life/2" Version="2.20.00">
    <TXLifeRequest PrimaryObjectID="Holding_1">
        <CorrelationGUID>4b30545a-158b-441a-a37a-0b259f757059</CorrelationGUID>
    </TXLifeRequest>
</TXLife>'

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://ACORD.org/Standards/Life/2')
SELECT t.c.value('CorrelationGUID[1]', 'UNIQUEIDENTIFIER')
FROM @XML.nodes('//TXLifeRequest') t(c)
```

Output -

```
------------------------------------
4B30545A-158B-441A-A37A-0B259F757059
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the namespace. Try this:

```
SELECT
  XMLDATA.value('declare namespace L="http://ACORD.org/Standards/Life/2";(//L:CorrelationGUID)[1]',
                'UNIQUEIDENTIFIER') AS 'TransType'
FROM   @test

UNION ALL

SELECT
  C.value('declare namespace L="http://ACORD.org/Standards/Life/2";(./L:CorrelationGUID)[1]',
          'UNIQUEIDENTIFIER') AS 'TransType'
FROM   @test
CROSS APPLY
  XMLDATA.nodes('declare namespace L="http://ACORD.org/Standards/Life/2";/L:TXLife/L:TXLifeRequest') N(C)
```

See it working [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/19616).